# HAProxy and URL Rewriting Configuration

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting, nginx, haproxy

I would like to ask how HAProxy can help in routing requests depending on parts of the URL.

To give you an overview of my setup, I have the HAProxy machine and the two backends:

- IIS website (main site)
- Wordpress blog on NGINX (a subsite)

---

**The use-case:**

I'm expecting to route requests depending on the URL:

- www.website.com/lang/index.aspx -> main site
- www.website.com/lang/blog/articlexx -> blog subsite

The blog access URL is "*/server/blog/lang/articlexx*" so I have to rewrite the original client request to that format--which is basically switching "blog" and "lang".

From how I understood the configuration documentation and some posts on the net, I could use reqrep/reqirep to change the request HTTP headers before it gets passed to a backend. And if that's right, then this configuration should work:

```
frontend vFrontLiner
    bind            x.x.x.x:x
    mode            http
    option          httpclose
    default_backend iis_website

    # the switch: x/lang/blog -? x/blog/lang
    reqirep ^/(.*)/(blog)/(.*) /if\2/\1/\3

    acl blog path_beg -i /lang/blog/

    use_backend blog_website if blog


backend blog_website
    mode    http
    option  httpclose
    cookie  xxblogxx insert indirect nocache
    server  BLOG1 x.x.x.x:80 cookie s1 check inter 5s rise 2 fall 3
    server  BLOG2 x.x.x.x:80 cookie s2 check inter 5s rise 2 fall 3 backup
```

**The problem:** The requests being received by the blog_website backend is still the original URL "x/lang/blog".

I might have missed something on the regex part but my main concern is whether my understanding correct or not to use the reqirep in the first place. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks very much.

Comment: After reading this entry, I'm beginning to realize that the solution above is not possible.

http://serverfault.com/questions/189916/haproxy-per-server-url-rewriting-in-the-backend-reqirep

Comment: You do not want to change the URL based on the backend server selected by HaProxy.  Your switching entirely is done using `use_backend`, so the problem is the path-rewriting only, not the backend switching.  Rewriting can be done in the backend, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, you're assuming the server is in the request path. To match the request paths in the headers use a regex like this one:

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /lang/blog/(.*) \1\ /blog/lang/\2
```

you can use reqirep as well but that is only useful if your servers actually serve `/BLog/lAnG/` as well.

Comment: The regexp shall be either in frontend with `if blog` appended in the above case, or in the `blog_website` backend.  Also it should spell `reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /lang/blog/(.*) \1\ /blog/lang/\2` to not match Headers (the difference is a `:`).  And Cookies are not rewritten in case they have a `path=`, but this is difficult, anyway.

Comment: hi @Tino, I am facing the problem of cookies path after URL rewrite, do you able to share some sample on how to deal with that ?

Comment: @ThiamTeck I'd try something like `http-response replace-value Set-Cookie ;\ path=/blog/lang ;\ path=/lang/blog` see: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/9-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/ (Note: I think this page misses some '\' in the replacements examples.)  But above needs to be adapted to your needs, for example `path` may be just `/blog` - as I said, it is difficult.  CAVEAT: I did not test it nor needed it ever and all here was done just by the docs, not by testing it with HaProxy.

Answer (score 0):

If this still doesn't work switch to a stable version, e.g. as of now reqrep is broken in 1.5 dev. Switched to 1.4 to fix.